# iOS:service and characteristic uuids in Corebluetooth

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth

I have tried to get UUID from terminal using `$uuidgen` command

```
$ uuidgen   
8B312019-E7FF-4BE1-9B41-FAE4CE7792D8
```

I don't know that is weather service id or characteristic id. I have found in BTLE example like this

```
#define TRANSFER_SERVICE_UUID        @"8B312019-E7FF-4BE1-9B41-FAE4CE7792D8"
#define TRANSFER_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID    @"08590F7E-DB05-467E-8757-72F6FAEB13D4"
```

My question is how to get both UUIDS and place that as above?
please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Command `uuidgen` is used to generate some unique identifier,

After which you need to place that UUIDs on peripheral side (BLE device) as services and characteristics identifiers.
After this you can define that UUIDs on your central side (iPhone/iPad) and start reading/writing them.

***Example - you need to create a peripheral that gives "heart beet".***

For this purpose you need 1 BLE service that provides "heart beet", and also you need 1 characteristics that provides "heart beet" value.

**1)** we need to generate unique identifiers for "heart beet" service and "heart beet" value characteristic.

```
$ uuidgen
E284A3C0-54C6-48F9-8AC6-28CF0CD600F5
$ uuidgen
0A9373AF-E105-4E4E-8C04-091DA5C041E8
```

**2)** If you are also the hardware (peripheral) developer, you need to start your "heart beet" service under `E284A3C0-54C6-48F9-8AC6-28CF0CD600F5`, and "heart beet" characteristic under `0A9373AF-E105-4E4E-8C04-091DA5C041E8`.
If you are developing only iOS central application, than you need to send that uuids to hardware developer.

**3)** Now you can start reading "heart beet" value from peripheral like this

```
[LGUtils readDataFromCharactUUID:@"0A9373AF-E105-4E4E-8C04-091DA5C041E8"
                     serviceUUID:@"E284A3C0-54C6-48F9-8AC6-28CF0CD600F5"
                      peripheral:peripheral
                      completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                          NSLog(@"Data : %s Error : %@", (char *)[data bytes], error);
                      }];
```

*Also have a look to:*
https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/LGBluetooth
There are good examples, also you can use LGBluetooth for BLE communications,
that will make your job much more painless.

Comment: can u provide that API . Can u please explain what is deploying under enterprise . and if we developed through enterprise is there any chance to reject app by App Store.please let me know

Comment: aaah, sorry. good news :) you can interact with Classic bluetooth and submit it to AppStore without any problem. All you need is ExternalAccessoryFramework https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: see example http://www.ericd.net/2009/07/iphone-external-accessory-framework.html

Comment: i have read that documentation but its asking to give the protocols to info.plist .what are these protocols and from where we can get these .can i found any example for this

Comment: You need to ask manufactor for that, or try to reverse it from android application.

Comment: By using `[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories]` you may find the protocol strings.

Comment: @Larme I think the data exchange protocol will not be so simple for guessing :)

Comment: @l0gg3r: The protocol strings (for the MFi) is not the same as the "communication protocol" (how to start remote action, get info, etc.). But you should add either way the protocol strings (which is a property of `EAAccessory`).